# Image search engine, but for logos / How do you spot plagiarized logos?

Tags: logo, images

Is there such a thing?

A search engine where you're able to upload an image with a logo, and you get results of sites that are using that logo :)

I tried Googles image search: http://www.google.com/imghp (click on the camera, then upload image), but the results are pretty poor.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

http://www.tineye.com/ is a great reverse image search. It basically searches through the internet to find images that are identical or very similar to your own.

There is no perfect 1-stop-get-all solution, but it's a start.

**Edit**

Google images also has a feature now that lets you click-and-drag an image into the search bar and it will find all similar images.

Answer (score 6):

The best option here I'm aware of is the [Google Chrome extension **RevEye**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/reveye-reverse-image-sear/keaaclcjhehbbapnphnmpiklalfhelgf?hl=en).

It allows you to right click on any image and do a 'reverse image search' with many reverse image search services at once:

[image]

- Google image-based search (this search includes relevant web pages as well as 'visually similar images' and matching images)
- [Tin Eye](http://www.tineye.com/)
- Cydral (this service seems to be down at the moment)
- [Yandex reverse image search](http://images.yandex.ru/) (Russian search engine)
- [Baidu reverse image search](http://stu.baidu.com/) (Chinese search engine)

I imagine they'll update the extension as and when new services emerge. Yandex and Baidu usually find nothing, but are probably worth including if you're trying to be thorough - when they do include something, it's quite often not listed in Google or TinEye.

---

If your image is **a file on your machine, not on a web page**, just open the image file using Chrome, then right-click and RevSearch as above.

---

There are also equivalent extensions for most individual reverse image search tools ([e.g. Google](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/search-by-image-by-google/dajedkncpodkggklbegccjpmnglmnflm/related?hl=en), and [various individual ones for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?q=reverse%20image%20search&appver=&platform=) which, as usual for firefox extensions, mostly don't work with the latest version).

I find reverse image search to be so hit-and-miss that it's useful to be able to search all available services at once.

Answer (score 2):

The Global Brand Database maintained by the World Intellectual Property Organization (WIPO) has millions of logos, but their image comparison isn't that great
https://www.wipo.int/branddb/en/

Answer (score 1):

Imageraider is pretty good at this. Also try https://euipo.europa.eu/eSearch/ or the paid https://trademark.vision/. Either way, looking inside the United States database of trademarked logos is still not easy.